# C# - Convert HTML unordered list to array

Tags: c#, html, regex

My HTML string is like this , stored in a variable named `sourceCode`

```
    <ul class="yom-list col first" style="width:33.333333333333%">
    <li class="first">
      <a href="/india/andaman-and-nicobar-islands/">
        <span>Andaman and Nicobar Islands</span>
      </a>
    </li>
      <li>
      <a href="/india/jammu-and-kashmir/">
        <span>Jammu and Kashmir</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="last">
      <a href="/india/andhra-pradesh/">
        <span>Andhra Pradesh</span>
      </a>
    </li>
      <li>
      <a href="/india/jammu-and-kashmir/">
        <span>Jammu and Kashmir</span>
      </a>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

I want to convert it in to a generic List
So that I can access the data inside it in my code like href, name etc..
I have tried something like this

```
            foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(sourceCode, @"<li><a href=""(?<url>[^""])</a></li>"))
            items.Add(new Item()
            {

                name = match.Groups["span"].Value, // i don't know how to get value inside that span
                url = match.Groups["url"].Value,

            });
```

But it does not work, Probably the regex is wrong. Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong?
**Note: I can't use HTMLAgilityPack in this project**

Comment: If you are using `XHTML`, how about trying to use an XML Parser?

Comment: @rhughes This is just a string , which holds html tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below regex to get the values between `<a href>` tag and `<span>` tag only if it is present inside `<li>` tag.

```
/<li>\s*<a href=\"(?<url>[^"]*)\">\s*<span>(?<span>[^<]*)<\/span>/m
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wN4wB7/1)

Your `c#` code would be,

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"<li>\s*<a href=""(?<url>[^""]*)"">\s*<span>(?<span>[^<]*)</span>");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
{
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["url"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["span"].Value);
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/xUWfnk)

Comment: I am not able to add this regex inside my C# code Probably the syntax is different

Comment: @Athul see the IDEONE link on my answer.